# Does SPDY benefit SEO rankings?

Tags: seo, page-speed, spdy

Google have stated that speed is a ranking factor:
https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/

Does implementing SPDY have any consequence for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Googlebot is not currently SPDY enabled as of 2014-12-30.

Although Googlebot will not be detecting faster load times as a result of SPDY, there may be an indirect benefit from improved user experience from faster load times.

Faster load times may result in better user experience which can increase "engagement" on your site. Google measures engagement in different ways.

For example a very slow site will have a lot of users pogo sticking (http://moz.com/blog/solving-the-pogo-stick-problem-whiteboard-friday) back to the SERP results  which will have a negative effect on ranking.

Answer (score 4):

There is no arbitrary bonus for using SPDY so SPDY  itself does not affect SEO.

But SPDY  can make your site more responsive (i.e. load faster) which is a ranking factor so it can indirectly affect your rankings. But so far Google has stated that page speed only affects the rankings of a small segment of websites )probably the slowest) and most sites won't notice a difference.

Comment: How do you know that Google takes into account SPDY when measuring site speed?

Comment: They don't take it into account. They notice its affects. Using SPDY *should* result in faster page loads.

Comment: As well, speed is not as much a factor as you would think. Google does not reward fast sites as much as it downgrades slow sites. The reason for this is simple, there is such a wide acceptable site speed range that it makes no sense to reward a faster than average sites. The intent was to keep search users happy with the results. A site that is a few nano-seconds faster makes no difference to a user. But a site that is 6 seconds slower, does. As well, site speeds can vary so much from time to time, that it is impossible to really slice and dice faster response times.

Comment: @JohnConde Do you know for a fact that the googlebot is spdy enabled?

Comment: Google invented SPDY so I'm going to go on a limb and say, yes.

Comment: I wouldnt be so sure...google describe SPDY themselves as an "experimental protocol". I wouldnt be so sure they would use an experimental protocol on their webbot.

Comment: It used to be experimental. Now it is the foundation of HTTP 2.0.

Comment: Googlebot is not SPDY enabled: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74074/does-googlebot-support-spdy